# Is ICollection<T> mandatory in a one-to-many relationship on an Entity Framework model, even if I never plan to make use of it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, if I have a one-to-many relationship with one Course entity and many Subscription entities, do I have to add an ICollection< Subscription > property to my Course entity, even if I never intend to make use of it?  In other words, does it cause any problems if I leave it off of the Course entity (besides what one could argue is a lack of forethought for possible future design changes)?

I am asking in part because I am getting a rare database duplication issue with my Courses which I cannot track down, and am wondering if this could be the culprit.

Comment: if your question is: "i don't need this field, can i delete it from my code?" the answer would seem to be "yes"

Comment: if you're asking if you can maintain a one-many relationship without the pieces of code that you need in order to have a one-many relationship, then the answer is "no"

Comment: I can't imagine duplicate Courses to be related to the lack of a collection. But this is impossible to answer without seeing code that causes the duplicates.